# How do you import multiple VCF or CSV Files to Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts, import

I was trying to find a way to import multiple VCF/CSV contacts to Google Contacts in one shot, instead of adding one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Source:
http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/import-multiple-contacts-into-gmail-from-outlook-mail-thunderbird-vcf-csv/

**Combining Multiple .VCF or .CSV Files for Importing**

Unfortunately, there isn’t any batch import for vcf and csv contacts in Gmail. A workaround for this is to take all your vCard or exported contact files and combine them into a single file and then upload that one master file.

**Steps for Windows**

Step 1: Launch a command prompt by Clicking the Start button and typing Cmd and pressing Enter.

Step 2: Go to the directory where your exported contacts are located.

Step 3: Type:

```
COPY *.csv combinedfile.csv
```

and Press Enter. Or, if you’re combining .vcf files, type

```
COPY *.vcf combinedfile.vcf
```

and Press Enter.
[image: CMD Command]

Step 4:
Next steps are pretty straightforward, go to contacts, click on More -> Import, and select the appropriate option. Upload the file and you are done!

**Combining Exported Contacts in OS X**

To perform this same task in OS X, launch Terminal, go to the directory that has your exported contacts and type:

```
fmt -sp *.vcf > combinedfile.vcf
```

…or

```
fmt -sp *.csv > combinedfile.csv
```

[image: Mac CMD Instructions]

Comment: I tried the windows trick, but google didn't like the new combined.vcf file and wouldn't import it.

Answer (score 0):

Open powershell and type `cat *.vcf > .\merge\merge.vcf`